# Running Coded-UI in TFS 2017 as part of the build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

As per the documentation, in order to run Coded-UI as part of the build you need to have your build agent running as interactive Mode (Not as a service) also your Test Agent need to be deployed as Interactive Mode.

Now the problem is when you deploy your test agent your build machine will restart automatically so  your Build agent will not restart cause its not a a service.

How can you work around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you would like to run Coded UI test, you have to configure the test agent to interact with the Desktop and build agent running as interactive Mode.

If you insist on installing the TFS Test agent on the same machine as the Build agent.  You need to manually [install and configure the agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents) first. Then specify the test agent installation media path in test agent deploy task and use *Run Functional Test* task to [run Automated Test on agent machine](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/08/05/running-automated-test-on-agent-machine-using-vnext-build/).

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. Don't use the build server as a test agent. Depending on the complexity and size of the test suite, you can either run the tests directly on the deployed environment or have a dedicated group of test machines to parallelize the run.
2. Install the test agent outside of a build process and just use the "run functional tests" task to connect to the already-running agent. The "Install test agent" task is really for scenarios closer to option #1, especially if you're doing things like provisioning test machines in the cloud on-demand.